# Permutation tree not making sense with the code

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I watched a youtube video where [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j2qV.png) basic permutation tree was shown. If you look at this bit of code:

```
    function recursion(input, set = [], result = []) {
        if (!input.length) {
           result.push([...set].join(''));
         }

        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            const newArr = input.filter((n, index) => index !== i);
            set.push(input[i]);
            recursion(newArr, set, result);
            set.pop();
         }
         return result.join(', ');
}
```

you can see that the base case (if statement) is at the top before the parameter nums is filtered. So, my whole question is how the tree and the code makes sense because for me the code would remove one too many digits from the set array. Becuase it pops an item of when returning and doesn't it return more than two times?

Comment: Please show actual text, not images of text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @VLAZ. Ok, fixed. I can't put an image in the post so I had to link one instead.

Comment: I think the edits add enough clarity that I'm voting to reopen.  But I'm going to suggest that you play computer and try walking through that code; it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this log add clarity?

```
/ entering recursion with input = [1,2,3], set = [], result = []
| looping, i = 0
| adding  1 to set
|   / entering recursion with input = [2,3], set = [1], result = []
|   | looping, i = 0
|   | adding  2 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [3], set = [1,2], result = []
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  3 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [1,2,3], result = []
|   |   |   | adding 123 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123]
|   |   | removing  3 from set
|   |   \ returning [123]
|   | removing  2 from set
|   | looping, i = 1
|   | adding  3 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [2], set = [1,3], result = [123]
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  2 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [1,3,2], result = [123]
|   |   |   | adding 132 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123,132]
|   |   | removing  2 from set
|   |   \ returning [123,132]
|   | removing  3 from set
|   \ returning [123,132]
| removing  1 from set
| looping, i = 1
| adding  2 to set
|   / entering recursion with input = [1,3], set = [2], result = [123,132]
|   | looping, i = 0
|   | adding  1 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [3], set = [2,1], result = [123,132]
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  3 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [2,1,3], result = [123,132]
|   |   |   | adding 213 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123,132,213]
|   |   | removing  3 from set
|   |   \ returning [123,132,213]
|   | removing  1 from set
|   | looping, i = 1
|   | adding  3 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [1], set = [2,3], result = [123,132,213]
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  1 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [2,3,1], result = [123,132,213]
|   |   |   | adding 231 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231]
|   |   | removing  1 from set
|   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231]
|   | removing  3 from set
|   \ returning [123,132,213,231]
| removing  2 from set
| looping, i = 2
| adding  3 to set
|   / entering recursion with input = [1,2], set = [3], result = [123,132,213,231]
|   | looping, i = 0
|   | adding  1 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [2], set = [3,1], result = [123,132,213,231]
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  2 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [3,1,2], result = [123,132,213,231]
|   |   |   | adding 312 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231,312]
|   |   | removing  2 from set
|   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231,312]
|   | removing  1 from set
|   | looping, i = 1
|   | adding  2 to set
|   |   / entering recursion with input = [1], set = [3,2], result = [123,132,213,231,312]
|   |   | looping, i = 0
|   |   | adding  1 to set
|   |   |   / entering recursion with input = [], set = [3,2,1], result = [123,132,213,231,312]
|   |   |   | adding 321 to result
|   |   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231,312,321]
|   |   | removing  1 from set
|   |   \ returning [123,132,213,231,312,321]
|   | removing  2 from set
|   \ returning [123,132,213,231,312,321]
| removing  3 from set
\ returning [123,132,213,231,312,321]
```

You can see how I added the logging to your code in this snippet:

```js
const log = (depth, message) => 
  console .log ('|   '.repeat (depth)  + message)


function recursion(input, set = [], result = [], depth = 0) {
    log (depth, `/ entering recursion with input = [${input}], set = [${set}], result = [${result}]`)
    if (!input.length) {
        log (depth, `| adding ${[...set].join('')} to result`)
        result.push([...set].join(''));
     }

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        log (depth, `| looping, i = ${i}`)
        const newArr = input.filter((n, index) => index !== i);
        log (depth, `| adding  ${input[i]} to set` )
        set.push(input[i]);
        recursion(newArr, set, result, depth + 1);
        log (depth, `| removing  ${input[i]} from set` )
        set.pop();
    }
    log (depth, `\\ returning [${result}]`)
    return result.join(', ');
}

console .log (recursion([1, 2, 3]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(but the console output there is limited to the last 50 lines.)

Comment: "*(but the console output there is limited to the last 50 lines.)*" you can see the full output in the browser console.